# JsTree - Select node when the panel is hidden

Tags: jquery, jstree

I have a JS tree and below is the html and the js to select a node on click of a button. Now, I want to know if there is any way to select a node if the tree is placed in a collapsible panel and is hidden ( **div -> #tree**) and the button is placed outside. I tried but in vain.

Assuming at first only the parent is visible.

```
<div>
<button onclick="select()">
Sample
</button>
<div id="tree" style="width:40%; float:left;"></div>
</div>

$(function () {
    $("#tree")
    .jstree({
        "core": {
            "data": [{"text":"Parent","children":[{"id" : "nodeId", "text":"Child1"}]}]
        }
    });
});

function select() {
    $("#tree").jstree(true).select_node("nodeId");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all works fine as far as you place your javascript before the markup. Otherwise the button doesn't know about the `select` function yet since it is declared later. You can see this error on browser console.

Here is how you can make it work - [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/cd97m0jk/).